# Excel and CSV import with approval before insert to database OOP PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop, csv

I am creating a data import and export system in OOP PHP and MySQL I want to upload Excel files and store the file path and name in the MySQL database table with such columns (id, file name, file path, status, date) the file content can only be imported/inserted into a certain table when the file upload has been approved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What i need was how to store a path in the database table that can be used to retrieve data in the excel sheet. i have managed to solve the challenge i had

Answer (score 0):

I finally go the Answer to my question.

this is the upload and insert toa db Code

```
public function checkUploadedStatus($submit,$file) 
{
   $this->uploadedStatus = 0;

if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {
//if there was an error uploading the file
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else 
{

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
        $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $status='Not Apoproved';
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $uploadDir ='../Uploaded_files/';
        $description =$_POST['description'];
        $Logged_user =$_POST['Logged_user'];
        $user_email =$_POST['user_email'];
        $user_sector =$_POST['user_sector'];
        $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);


    // Check to see if file exists in uploads folder 

    if (file_exists($uploadDir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
      $_SESSION["uploadMessage"] = $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists in Uploads folder";
    }
    // If it doesn't move to uploads folder

    elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filePath))
       $_SESSION["uploadMessage"]= "Stored in: " .$filePath;


        // Filename to be persisted for uploading data to MySQL

        $_SESSION["inputFileName"]= $filePath;

         if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                      {
                     $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
                     $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
                       }

                    $uploaded =true;

                 if($uploaded)
                 {

              //prep the data for saving in a new user object
                    $data['name'] = $fileName;
                    $data['size'] = $fileSize;
                    $data['type'] = $fileType;
                    $data['path'] = $filePath;
                    $data['status'] = $status;
            $data['description'] = $description;
            $data['date'] = $date;

             //create the new file upload object
           $newUpload = new DB ($data);

        //save the new file upload to the database

        $data = array (
            "name" => "'$fileName'",
            "size" => "'$fileSize'",
            "type" => "'$fileType'",
            "path" => "'$filePath'",
            "description" => "'$description'",
            "uploadedby" => "'$Logged_user'",
            "useremail" => "'$user_email'",
            "date" => "'$date'"
                  );
           $id = $newUpload->insert($data, 'file_uploads');
           $uploadsaved =true;
```

and this is the retrieve code

```
 $Upload_id = $_GET['id'];

$upload = $db->selectData("file_uploads"," id = $Upload_id");

foreach ($upload as $urows) {
$Upload_id = $urows['id'];
$fileName = $urows['name'];
$path = $urows['path'];}
$file = "../Uploaded_files/" .$fileName;

$inputFileName = $file;

try {
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  die('Error loading   file"'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'"'.$e->getMessage());}

 $allDataInSheet=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

// Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet
 $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  

for($i=2;$i<= $arrayCount;$i++)
{

$ID= trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
$indicator= trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
$survey_date=trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);
 $county=trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]);
$aggregate=trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]);
}
```